# How to Create Indent through Multiple Objects without Using Multiple Loop Cuts?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

so I'm trying to make this in ground pool design.

The only method I know right now is to create loop cuts on each layer of my design, then extrude the faces where the pool water is located downwards.

Like below, however I have 2 objects (grass + dirt) so only the grass loop cuts were added, but then I need to go to the dirt and add loop cuts there.

[image]

Is there a better method for creating this indent for the pool that goes into both the grass and dirty layer that doesn't involve making these loop cuts?

Answer (score 3):

One other possibility is using a boolean modifier with a cube (as your pool). Then you have only to add this modifier to all your of your layers.

[image]

your boolean modifier:

[image]

Now select all your layers and at last your modifier with your boolean modifier, then CTRL-L -> copy modifiers.

The advantage to loopcuts is that you can still adapt your pool:

[image]

[image]

Comment: when I create a new empty cube and use it as the object for my modifier, then I copy them across my layers, it doesn't indent like in your gif

Comment: can you please provide your blend file so i can have a look? i will also provide mine so maybe you find the reason yourself.